# How do I remove a tag in CVS with an illegal character in it?

Tags: cvs

Through some twist of fate, we have a tag in our CVS repository that has a "/" character in it.  We need to delete it, but when trying to run the delete command, we get the response:

cvs [rtag aborted]: tag `mytag/' must not contain the characters`$,.:;@/'

We also asked our CVS administrators if they could remove the tag, but they said they ALSO can't remove it, getting a similar error. How can we (or the admins) delete the tag?

Answer (score 1):

I would only recommend this as a last resort, but worst case, if you can't figure out another way to do it, the CVS repository on the server just stores each files textfiles, RCS files, with the tags listed in successive lines near the top. With access to the source repository, you can always just remove the lines with the offending tag from every `,v` file. Obviously only ever do this on a copy first and ensure that it works.